# Queryset containing related Object with same foreignkey

Tags: python, django

e.g. I've a person with an address

```
class Persons(models.Model):
adress = models.ForeignKey(Adress, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True,
                                   null=True)
class Adress(models.Model):
some_data = models.IntegerField()
```

and i have another related data in antoher model like this

```
class Places(models.Model):
adress = models.ForeignKey(Adress, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

how can i get a queryset now of both persons and places if adress is set in persons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the `Places` of a `Persons` object with:

```
Places.object.filter(adress__persons=myperson)
```

If you want to do this in bulk, you can work with:

```
qs = Persons.objects.select_related('adress').prefetch_related('adress__places_set')
```

this will load the related `Places` in bulk, so you can fetch these with:

```
for person in qs:
    print(person.adress.places_set.all())
```

Comment: thank you, but how shall i handle persons if adress is None?

Comment: @SamPhoenix: if the `adress` is `None`, then there are no `Places` related to it. So you should indeed check if `person.adress` is not `None`.

Comment: but how can i finally display the given data in a template then? .all() just returns the object

Comment: @SamPhoenix: you enumerate over it, with `{% for place in person.address.places_set.all %}{{ place.some_field }}{% endfor %}`.

Comment: @SamPhoenix: please don't use `0`, if there are *multiple* `Places` for an `Adress`, then you will only retrieve the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do somethings like this but first you need to add `related_name` in your Persons and Places Foreign key

```
class Persons(models.Model):
     adress = models.ForeignKey(Adress,related_name = "persons_adress",on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True,null=True)
```

```
class Adress(models.Model):
     some_data = models.IntegerField()
```

```
class Places(models.Model):
     adress = models.ForeignKey(Adress, related_name = "places_addres",on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

After this alteration you can now query

```
Adress.objects.filter(persons_adress__some_data = some_data,places_addres__some_data = some_data)
```